# How to solve error: expected identifier or '('

Tags: c, cs50

I've got a problem with something I'm programming.
I get this error over and over;

```
jharvard@appliance (~/Dropbox/pset1): make mario
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Werror    mario.c  -lcs50 -lm -o mario
mario.c:23:5: error: expected identifier or '('
    do
    ^
mario.c:32:1: error: expected identifier or '('
do
^
2 errors generated.
```

I searched all over the internet but couldn't find the problem.. 
removing the ; after `int main(void)` didn't help

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void);

    //Ask User for Height, and check

    int a, b, rows, height;
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int rows = 1;   

    do
    { 
        printf ("Height: ");
        height = GetInt();
    }
    while (height <=0 || height > 23);   

    //build half pyramid

    do
    {
        do
        {
            printf("r");
            a++;
        }
        while (a < height - rows);

        do
        {
            printf("#");
            b++;
        }
        while (b < rows + 1);


        printf("\n");
        rows++;

        while (rows <= height);
    }
```

I've been trying to solve this problem for a few days, but i just can't figure it out!

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Fix your indentation, that last while looks really strange there all alone.

Comment: It's because of missing `}` before `printf` of `while` (depends on the real body cycle, don't know what you really mean because of bad indentation)

Comment: +1 to what @Mat said. The last while look like it should be after the closing bracket (which belongs to the second `do`). But indent your code, and such mistakes will be obvious to you. If you don't indent your code, than you deserve to suffer like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You got nested loop with do/while. Make sure that each start with do end with while.

Look like at the end of file, the "while" is not correct.

```
printf("\n");
rows++;

while (rows <= height);
}
```

That could be you missing the close '}' before 'while (rows <= height);'

Correct code could be:

```
int main(void)
{

    //Ask User for Height, and check

    int a, b, rows, height;
    a = 0;                    // <- removed int
    b = 0;                    // <- removed int
    rows = 1;                 // <- removed int

    do
    { 
        printf ("Height: ");
        height = GetInt();
    }
    while (height <=0 || height > 23);   

    //build half pyramid

    do
    {
        do
        {
            printf("r");
            a++;
        }
        while (a < height - rows);

        do
        {
            printf("#");
            b++;
        }
        while (b < rows + 1);


        printf("\n");
        rows++;
    }                             // <- add }
    while (rows <= height);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

```
int main(void);
```

You have just declared the `main`. You need to define it and add the code inside that definition.

```
int main()
{
   .....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Main post is edited, so clear answer.

All your code is outside of a function because you're doing int main(); you're declaring a function. Use {} brackets instead.

```
int main() {
    //Code here.
}
```

Comment: He's not. It's at the bottom, or so it seems

Comment: It's confusing with that indentation.

Answer (score 2):

```
int a, b, rows, height;
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
```

Here in your above statements `a` and `b` are re-declared more than once causing compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

Take the last while outside of the do scope:

```
while (rows <= height);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't indent your code, which you (by all means) should do, *at least* write the starting and the ending curly brackets at once when you write the loop statement, before putting any code into that loop's body (which goes between the curly brackets). It will save you from troubles like these in the future.

Answer (score -1):

In case of react native project .... its a simple issue.

You can go to you project target in ios and check Build, version and build identifier... they might have extra space on the end which should be removed

Hope it helps. Worked for me