# error: expected identifier or '(' for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)

Tags: debugging, cs50

Hey guys this error has been recurring, and I'm not sure what's the issue.

error: expected identifier or '('
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int get_positive_int(string prompt);

int main(void)
{
  int i = get_positive_int("Positive Integer: ");
  printf("%i\n", i);

}

// Prompt user for positive integer 
int get_positive_int (string prompt)
{
  int n; 
  do
  {
    n = get_int("%s", prompt);
  }
  while (n <0 || n > 8);
  return n;
}


    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    { 
        {
            printf("#");    
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Comment: your last bit isn't in any function.

Comment: similar problems : https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/24558/pset1-error-expected-identifier-or and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011644/how-to-solve-error-expected-identifier-or

Answer (score 0):

The for loop must be inside some function.